# Dynamic CRUD operations in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I've created CRUD operations for my treeview list but they are static - the page reloads on submit the data to controller. How do I make it dynamic, so the page won't have to reload any time I add, delete or edit an element.
It this case I just want to know how to do that for ADD operation.

View:

```
@helper PopulateDivs(List<Tree_List.Controllers.Element> elements)
{

    <ul>
        @foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            <li>
                <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="@element.ID" data-parent="@element.PARNET_ID" @*style="display:none"*@>
                    <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="@element.ID" data-parent="@element.PARNET_ID">+</button>
                    @element.NAME
                    <button class="add_btn" type="button" data-id="@element.ID">Add</button>
                    <button class="edit_btn" type="button" data-id="@element.ID" data-parent="@element.PARNET_ID">Edit</button>
                    <button class="delete_btn" type="button" data-id="@element.ID">Delete</button>
                    <ul id="childItems-@element.ID"></ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

CONTROLLER METHOD FOR CREATE:

```
     //MODAL POPUP FOR CREATE

        public ActionResult CreateNewItem(int id)
        {
            if (id == 0)
            {
                H_Table item = new H_Table();
                return PartialView(item);
            }
            else
            {
                H_Table item = db_connection.H_Table.Find(id);
                return PartialView(item);
            }

        }

        //POST: CREATE ITEM

        [HttpPost]
//        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult CreateNewItem(string name, int parent)
        {
            H_Table item = new H_Table();
            if (parent == 0)
            {
                item.NAME = name;
                item.PARENT_ID = null;
            }
            else
            {
                item.PARENT_ID = parent;
                item.NAME = name;
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db_connection.H_Table.Add(item);
                db_connection.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(item);
        }
```

JS:

```
        $('body').on('click', '.add_btn', function () {
        $.get("/List/CreateNewItem", { id: $(this).data('id') }, function (data) {
            $('#modal_window').replaceWith('<div id="modal_window">' + data + '</div>');
            $('#modal_window').show();
        });
    });
```

Partial View for Create:

```
    @model Tree_List.Models.H_Table

<form action="/List/CreateNewItem" method="post">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>CREATE NEW ITEM</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="control-label col-md-2">NAME</div>

            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input name="name" type="text" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="control-label col-md-2">PARENT</div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input name="parent" type="text" value="@Model.ID" readonly />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to have a page that updates itself without a reload or a postback, your html list must be an ajax component. You won't be able to have this behaviour with a simple

```
 @foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            <li>
                ...
            </li>
        }
```

I'm not familiar with asp.net ajax components so i suggest you to check that (telerik has some).
Or you can just update your Javascript: populate the list from an ajax call and update the list by adding a row after your  "ADD" call.

although it's generally better to start looking for a front end framework (react, angular, etc) when going like that.